# Sqoop Hive import

Tags: hive, sqoop, bigdata

I am trying to import a table from MySql database to hive table to understand how hive import works.The table name is device which I have already imported in HDFS in home directory in HDFS. I created a table in hive using below statement.

```
create table device_hive (device_num int,device_name varchar(255));
```

Now I am executing below sqoop import statement to get the data from `device` table in  Mysql database to Hive

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --table device
--username training --password training --hive-import --hive-table device_hive 
--hive-database hadoopexam --hive-table device_hive --fields-terminated-by '\001' 
--table device --columns "device_num,device_name"
```

Its failing stating that output directory device is already exists.The location in error message points to the `device` folder in HDFS which I imported using sqoop earlier.

My question is why sqoop is going to base directory and checking for that folder. It's a hive-import so shouldn't sqoop just go to hive/warehouse directory? I delete that folder from HDFS and it works fine. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_import_process)

> By default, imports go to a new target location. If the destination
>   directory already exists in HDFS, Sqoop will refuse to import and
>   overwrite that directory’s contents.

So if you already imported the table into HDFS, the error that the `device` directory already exists would be the normal behavior. When you add the `--hive-import` command, Sqoop copies the data into HDFS (in your case, in the `device` directory) and updates the Hive metastore with the data's layout.

You could use the [--hive-overwrite](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) option in order to tell Sqoop to overwrite the table:

> If the Hive table already exists, you can specify the --hive-overwrite
>   option to indicate that existing table in hive must be replaced.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how Sqoop import into hive works.

It works in 3 steps:

- Import data to HDFS *(HOME_DIRECTORY/TABLE_NAME)*
- CREATE HIVE TABLE....
- LOAD DATA INPATH...

As per [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive),

> After your data is imported into HDFS or this step is omitted, Sqoop will generate a Hive script containing a CREATE TABLE operation defining your columns using Hive’s types, and a LOAD DATA INPATH statement to move the data files into Hive’s warehouse directory.

In your case, it's failing at 1st step.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Import control argument `--delete-target-dir`. It will Delete the import target directory if it exists.